# Display a list of strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, list, jsp

I have a jsp file in which am getting a List of strings from a java file, i.e., `List<String>`.
In the jsp, using js I want to return a string that has the contents of the string list concatenated.
I tried doing :

```
function getStrList(param1, param2)
{
var w;
var i;
    sendAjaxPostRequest("/api/upgrade/application/getList","p1="+param1+"&p2="+param2,function(resp) {

        w= resp.strList;

        for ( var i in strList )
        { 
            alert("inside for...");
            w += i;
        }

        });
    return w;
}
```

Nothing inside the for loop is executing.

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:java]?

Comment: `JavaScript` works on client side. But Java and your `List<String>` exists on sever side.

Comment: I got the list of strings from a java file.. made an ajax call to it.

Comment: @Anjana rather important information to add to your question, don't you think? And also expanding the code to illustrate how this tiny snippet is executed, since your biggest problem is that it isn't executed at all.

Comment: Then you need to clarify your question. For now it looks like `listStr` is `List<String>`, not its copy which you got via ajax.

Comment: sorry. I have edited the question. Please see.

Answer (score 0):

Q.) How much you are aware of working with jsp.

you need to assign a variable to java value. for-ex below variable row is assigned to systemcheckmap. Then you ned to create a javascript variable to which you will assign this variable.
Here I make use of jsp tag library to set variable.

```
<c:set value="${systemcheckmap}" var="row" scope="request"/>
<script>
var test = ${row};
</scrip>
```

Now you can iterate over test variable in JavaScript.

Comment: I have assigned    w= resp.strList;

Comment: Did you noticed use of ${ } around row variable. Please try this. If this doesn't work please provide full code snippet.